# Running a downloaded program after make

Tags: c++, makefile

I'm trying to run [some software](https://github.com/mmorise/NoiseGenerators) I downloaded.

I was able to run make, this happens:

```
**xx-mbp NoiseGenerators-master % make
**
mkdir -p ./build/objs/ng
g++ -O1 -Wall -fPIC  -Isrc -o "build/objs/ng/gaussianwhitenoise.o" -c "src/gaussianwhitenoise.cpp"
mkdir -p ./build/objs/ng
g++ -O1 -Wall -fPIC  -Isrc -o "build/objs/ng/modifiedvelvetnoise.o" -c "src/modifiedvelvetnoise.cpp"
mkdir -p ./build/objs/ng
g++ -O1 -Wall -fPIC  -Isrc -o "build/objs/ng/originalvelvetnoise.o" -c "src/originalvelvetnoise.cpp"
ar -rv ./build/libng.a ./build/objs/ng/gaussianwhitenoise.o ./build/objs/ng/modifiedvelvetnoise.o ./build/objs/ng/originalvelvetnoise.o 
ar: creating archive ./build/libng.a
a - ./build/objs/ng/gaussianwhitenoise.o
a - ./build/objs/ng/modifiedvelvetnoise.o
a - ./build/objs/ng/originalvelvetnoise.o
Done.
mkdir -p ./build/objs/test
g++ -O1 -Wall -fPIC  -Isrc -Itools -o "build/objs/test/test.o" -c "test.cpp"
g++ -O1 -Wall -fPIC  -o ./build/test ./build/objs/test/test.o ./build/libng.a -lm
```

Now, how do I "use" the software after that? I want to generate some noises! Do I need to enter more commands? Is there a visual interface?

Comment: Checkout the provided `README` type file for details. Every package includes *some* kind of instructions. Check that you're actually building a program and not just a library you're expected to include in other code.

Comment: It's a library, not an executable program. Libraries are piece of code that you use in the code you write. So, you'd need to write some program by yourself that will use the library.

Comment: You can look at the `./build/test` program maybe it does something useful

Comment: And maybe it downloads a tonne of kiddie porn and tries to blackmail you with it. How much can you really trust any program you get from the Internet?